# einen unserer köstlichen Nachtische versuchen wollen

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective

In this piece of dialog:

> Kunde: Ich möchte um 22 Uhr essen.
>
> Kellner: Die Küche schließt in der Woche um 22 Uhr 30.
> Und das is schade, wenn Sie einen unserer köstlichen Nachtische versuchen wollen.

Can someone please make sense of the cases of the words after the comma?

My try:

> ... wenn Sie einen unserer köstlichen Nachtische versuchen wollen.

I will rewrite it, for clarity like this:

> Sie versuchen einen unserer köstlichen Nachtische

- *versuchen* wants the accusative case, right?
- The noun *Nachtisch* is masculine, the plural is *Nachtische*.
- *einen* is in the accusative case.
- *unserer* and *köstlichen*  are adjectives. So, their declension should be that of plural adjectives following the indefinite article:
  *unsere köstliche Nachtische*

But it makes no sense because *einen* is singular.
I don't understand the "*einen unserer*" combination and therefore the necessary declension of the adjectives following it.

Comment: _"But it makes no sense because einen is singular"_ Sure it's singular, it's one out of many.

Comment: This is a prime example of a well posted question, not sure why you don't understand it and give -1...

Comment: @ infinitezero  I have added why

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver I guess the *not sure why you don't understand it* was addressed to the person who nominated your question for closing with the reason "unclear what you're asking" - it is indeed a well posted question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Versuchen sie den Nachtisch.

"Nachtisch" = accusative object (masculine).

> Versuchen sie unseren Nachtisch.

"unseren Nachtisch" = accusative object

"unseren" is used as an article, a possessive article. It is the accusative masculine form of "unser" because it is the article for "Nachtisch".

> Versuchen sie einen Nachtisch.

"einen Nachtisch" = accusative object.

Now "einen" is the article (accusative masculine).

> Versuchen sie einen unserer Nachtische.

Now "unserer" is a possessive determiner and not anymore the article! The article job is taken bei "einen"! A possessive determiner is genitive and "unserer" is the genitive masculine plural form of "unser".

Comment: @ Camissa I guess you meant "unserer" is the genitive plural form of unser, right ?

Comment: So I could say : Versuchen sie einen der Nachtische, and unserer takes the place of the plural genitive article der.  (Versuchen sie einen der unserer Nachtische would be incorrect)

Comment: Precisely, then it would need to be "einen der unseren Nachtische"

Comment: @juan carlos Yes, as “Nachtische” is plural it’s possessive determiner is plural too. I added that in my answer.

Comment: I suppose _einen_ is a pronoun here, not an article: "_Versuchen Sie mal einen." - "_Einen was?_" - "_Einen von unseren superleckeren Nachtischen._" In nominative, it would be _ein**er** unserer Nachtische_ ('einer' = pronoun), not *_ein unserer Nachtische_ ('ein' = article).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, versuchen takes the Akkusativ. And it does in this case, too! **einen** is the Akkusativ object. *Unserer köstlichen Nachtische* is in Genitiv, so the whole sentence translates to:

> [...] if you'd like to try **one** *of our tasty desserts*
>   [...] falls Sie **einen** *unserer leckeren Nachtische* versuchen wollen

Comment: I don't understand well this genitive structure.If Unserer köstlichen Nachtische is in Genitiv, don't I need a noun between einen and unserer?

Comment: I've added a comparison, maybe it becomes clearer this way

Answer (score 0):

I think ‘’einen’’ is a pronoun here so it’s not part of the ‘’unserer köstlichen Nachtische’’ which is genitiv plural noun . Actual pronoun is ‘’einer’’ but because versuchen takes accusative it becomes ‘’einen’’

Comment: I think it the full phrase it  comes from is : einen Nachtisch unserer köstlichen Nachtische (a dessert of our tasty deserts). and then to avoid repetition Nachtisch is dropped, so that einen, as you said , becomes a pronoun.  But why are you saying the actual pronoun is Einer? In the nominative you mean? Then the actual pronoun would be eine for plural nouns, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The word *unserer* is not some kind of attributive adjective but in actual fact a possessive pronoun. That would be true for all case-inflected forms of *unsere* (nominative plural). However, as [Canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Poss3.html?lang=en) states, these are often termed *possessive **articles*** rather than *possessive **pronouns*** in German, because if they are placed in front of a noun they act as an article.

> Versuchen Sie *unseren* köstlichen Nachtisch.
> Versuchen Sie *den* köstlichen Nachtisch.
> Versuchen Sie *einen* köstlichen Nachtisch.
>
> Schmeckt Ihnen *unser* Nachtisch?
> Schmeckt Ihnen *der* Nachtisch?

As the examples above show, you would either use an article (both definite or indefinite) *or* a possessive pronoun.

But your example sentence and your detailed analysis show that there is both an article *and* a pronoun, so what is going on here?

The answer is that the sentence does not mean:

> Try our delicious dessert.
> (Versuchen Sie unseren köstlichen Nachtisch.)

A rigorous examination shows that *unserer* is actually in genitive case while *einen* remains accusative (as you suspected). The translation that is not the above but rather:

> Try **one of** our delicious desserts.
> (Versuchen Sie **einen unserer** köstlichen Nachtische.)

This also explains the plural form; had it been ‘Versuchen Sie unsere köstlichen Nachtische’ (accusative plural) you would have been expected to try all or at least many desserts – but common restaurant practice in Germany would have you order only one dessert per person so you can only try one.

The German construction at play here is essentially *einer des Ganzen*: a demonstrative article (einer) followed by a genitive of a plural or group noun. Essentially, it is a *pick (any) one* situation exactly like its direct English translation *one of many*. It is permissible to use *einen von unseren Nachtischen*, more closely mirroring the English *one of*, but using the genitive is usually considered better practice.